# In ethereum, does the contract hosting account owns the either that's being sent to the contract too?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, remix

In ethereum, does the contract hosting account (the account where the contract is deployed to) owns the ether that's being sent to the contract? If not then what if contract gets deleted, does the ether gets sent back or just disappear.

Comment: I did a little experiment in this code on remix (https://github.com/qizhong19920114/distributed_exchange_truffle_class_3/blob/master/Practical%20Part%203/05DepositWithdrawalEther.sol) and obvious the either stored in the contract doesn't belong to the contract hosting account. So I really need help with the second part question, what if the contract gets destroyed, where will the ether go?

Comment: Hi, Trey. In the future, please consider editing the post itself, instead of putting edits or additional data in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

A contract *is* an account. (I *think* that's sort of what you mean by "contract hosting account?")

So yes, the contract owns its own ether. The only way a contract can be "deleted" is if it calls `selfdestruct(target)`, in which case the remaining ether balance of the contract is transferred to the address given in `target`.